Invalid Ukrainian layout with a physical keyboard and Microsoft SwiftKey
I have a HUAWEI tablet with the stock OS. The manufacturer only installed Microsoft SwiftKey. I connect a physical keyboard to the tablet, go to Settings, Language & input,

tap on “Physical keyboard”

tap “Microsoft SwiftKey Keyboard - Microsoft SwiftKey Keyboard” under “USB USB KEYBOARD”

select “Ukrainian”. Then I almost can type Ukrainian except that the key with “~ `” (tilde, backtick) produces “ё” instead of “'” (apostrophe). I experience this with two physical keyboards.
Is this because Microsoft SwiftKey manages my physical keyboard? How can I get a correct Ukrainian keyboard layout?

Similar to:Missing character in Android's keyboard layout for Hebrew

After installing More Physical Keyboard Layouts by călin, another layout “Ukrainian (Enhanced) Extra keyboard layouts” appeared in the “Keyboard layouts” list:

If I select it, the key with tilde produces an apostrophe!
